# Rust why is size of enum variant of (u32, u32) less than (u64)?

Tags: rust, enums, bit

Was looking into packing enums and while doing so I ran following program

```rust
enum SizeEnum {
    V1(u32, u32),
    // V2(u64),
    V3(u32, u32),
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", std::mem::size_of::<SizeEnum>());
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=342222c20fb08250e2e04e9bff04c6a4)

The output is 12 bytes (96 bits). What I expected was 16 bytes (128 bits). That's what happens when I uncomment `V2` variant.

Questions are:

1. So why does a `u32, u32` variant use less space than `u64`?
2. And why 12 bytes (96 bits) rather than something like 64+8 (72 bits)? I assume it's something about padding but would appreciate a detailed answer.

Comment: My guess: 1) The `u64` field makes it aligned to 8 bytes. 2) The `u32` fields make it aligned to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both questions boil down to alignment.

The `u32`s need to be aligned to 4 bytes. The `u64` needs to be aligned to 8 bytes.

Therefore, for the `u32` there are 3 bytes padding for the discriminant (so the `u32` is at the fourth byte) and for the `u64` there are seven.

Comment: Note that none of this is specified. It might vary from architecture to archtecture, from compiler version to compiler version or even from compiler run to compiler run.

Comment: Also it's not just that the u64 needs to be 8-aligned, but *structures are aligned to match their largest member*. So with an `u64` field, `SizeEnum` has to be aligned to 8 bytes, and its size needs to be a multiple of its alighment. With only u32 fields, it needs to be aligned to 4 and its size needs to be a multiple of 4.

Comment: @SvenMarnach generally alignment tends to get more constraining in weirder architectures though, or more specific uses (e.g. stack frames, vector buffers). Some popular archs (notably x64 which pretty much doesn't care in modern CPUs until you touch SSE -- or involve cross-core communications) deal well with unaligned data, but other architectures really don't like it.

Comment: @Masklinn I think this is less about architecture and more about ABI. As you already noted, x86 pretty much doesn't care about alignment, and it's still enforced by the compiler. Anoterh example is that 64-bit values are generally still 8-byte aligned on 32-bit architectures, even though they only have a 32-bit data bus, so the values need to be fetched in two halves anyway. In practice, the alignment is as stated in this answer. My point was that as a programmer, you shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it's absolutely architecture though, alignment cause issues for the ISAs (though they can also cause issues for the ABIs). According to [an old lwn article](https://lwn.net/Articles/260832/) there's actually been ISAs which couldn't do unaligned access but wouldn't tell you, instead they'd just return a different, aligned, memory access. x86 is famously lenient on unaligned access, but SSE is not and will usually SEGV (though apparently there's been some relaxations of SSE loads and stores in AVX).

Comment: Sure, it's architecture as well, but if it were _only_ architecture, we'd see a lot more relaxed alignment rules.